# Replace each occurrence of a substring with the return value of a function

Tags: php, html

I have a textbox that sends HTML data to the server, in this data, images are encoded in Base64, with my PHP script, i want to extract the Base64 data from the HTML then write it to an image file and replace the Base64 image data with the URL of the image file i just created. This is my code so far:

```
//this function takes the raw HTML data and extracts the Base64 data
function testFormat($string){
    $count = substr_count($string, "data:image");
    $title = "hello";
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $b64 = $this->get_string_between($string, "img src=\"", "\" ");
        while(strpos($b64, "data:") !== false){
            $rnd = rand(0, 99999);
            $img_url = $title . "-" . $rnd . ".jpg";
            $this->convertBase64ToImage($b64, $img_url);
            $string = str_replace($b64, $img_url, $string);
        }
    }
    return $string;
}

//this function converts Base64 text to image
function convertBase64ToImage($base64_string, $output_file){
    // open the output file for writing
    $ifp = fopen( $output_file, 'wb' ); 

    // split the string on commas
    // $data[ 0 ] == "data:image/png;base64"
    // $data[ 1 ] == <actual base64 string>
    $data = explode( ',', $base64_string );

    // add validation here with ensuring count( $data ) > 1
    fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $data[ 1 ] ) );

    // clean up the file resource
    fclose( $ifp ); 

    return $output_file; 
}

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$str = file_get_contents("file.txt");
var_dump($ps->testFormat($str));
```

The content of `"file.txt"`  https://pastebin.com/B5UTAH0n

The problem is that my code works only when there's only one (base64) image, if there are 2(like in the example) or more images, it only replaces the first occurrence, the other Base64 occurrences are not replaced. How can i get it replace every occerrence with the URL?

Comment: this function always picking first image only

Comment: @AlivetoDie  i figured that out, i thought since i changed the variable `$string` at the end of the for-loop in the `testFormat` function, when the loop runs again, it uses the new $string variable?